# Probability Distribution of a Correlated Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability

Suppose I have a Bivariate Normal Distribution (i.e. a Multivariate Normal Distribution with 2 Random Variables that each have Normal Distributions) - this looks something like this:

$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{|\boldsymbol{\Sigma}|}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol{\mu})\right)$$

In the above equation, we can write the "mean vector" and the "variance covariance matrix" as follows:

$$\boldsymbol{\mu} = \begin{pmatrix} \mu_1 \ \mu_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$\boldsymbol{\Sigma} =  \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{11} & \sigma_{12} \\
\sigma_{21} & \sigma_{22} \\
\end{pmatrix} $$

With this information, I know that I can calculate the Correlation between x1 and x2 - in this case:

$$\rho_{X_1,X_2} = \frac{\sigma_{X_1,X_2}}{\sigma_{X_1} \sigma_{X_2}}$$

**My Question:** I am interested in extending this logic and applying it to a **"Correlated Binomial Distribution"**. For example - suppose I am flipping a two sided coin: If HEADS, then the next flip is HEADS with p = 0.6 ELSE if TAILS, then the next flip is TAILS with p = 0.6.

In the case where this no correlation, I can write the Joint Probability Distribution of two Random Variables having a Binomial Distribution as follows:

$$f_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = {n_1 \choose x_1} p_1^{x_1} (1-p_1)^{n_1-x_1} {n_2 \choose x_2} p_2^{x_2} (1-p_2)^{n_2-x_2}$$

**But I am not sure how I can incorporate a "correlation structure" into this Joint Binomial Probability Distribution Function.**  Does such a distribution even exist - do we know its mean and variance?

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no unique joint distribution; infinitely many joint distributions would give rise to binomial marginal distributions.  This question has also been asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/231688/joint-distribution-of-dependent-binomial-random-variables).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Do you know how I can write a pdf of a correlated binomial distribution in general?

Comment: If $n_1=n_2$, you could start with correlated Bernoulli trials, then sum them.

Comment: "Correlation" between $X,Y$ only makes sense in the context of a *joint* distribution of $(X,Y)$ (otherwise, how do you compute correlation?).  However, there are infinitely many joint distributions that give rise to correlated binomial marginals. Also, the joint distribution you wrote is the case where the random variables are *independent* (uncorrelated does not imply independent).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your kind replies! much appreciated!